# QToolTip shows up in the wrong cordinates

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a QCustomPlot and I would like to show a QtoolTip on mouseover the component. Here is what I am using. This is my slot.

```
void CustomPlot::DisplayPlotValue(QMouseEvent* val)
{
     QToolTip::showText(val->pos(), "A tool tip");
}
```

However the tool tip aappears in the wrong cordinates (its infact out of the form that has my component) . Any suggestion on what i might be doing wrong ?

Comment: You are probably passing client coordinates when you should be passing screen coordinates, or vice versa. Check the API documentation and match up the results of `val->pos()` with what `QToolTip::showText` expects.

Comment: QToolTip::showText expects const QPoint & pos as the first argument [see](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtooltip.html#showText)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QWidget::mapToGlobal to map coordinates relative to a widget to global coordinates, which are relative to the whole screen:

```
QToolTip::showText(widget->mapToGlobal(val->pos()), "A tool tip");
```

where widget is your QWidget.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
QToolTip::showText(val->globalPos(), "A tool tip");
```